# Go back to the default fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Android app with one activity and two fragments. First fragment (`MainFragment`) show a list of "items" and second (`DetailsFragment`) display a item's details (very basic).

On the normal flow, the activity start and show first fragment and the second is shown when a item is clicked.

But the second fragment can be shown directly throught click on a notification (by putting extra arguments to the activity).

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (id != null) {
    fragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
} else {
    fragment = new MainFragment();
}

ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

In the second case, the problem is : How to open `MainFragment` when clicking back from `DetailsFragment` ? Actually the app finish because only the second fragment has been created.

Answer (score 2):

`First way:` Its very simple. You just need to use addToBackStack(null). It will save your desired fragment and when you use backpressed it will open that one.

Do something like this:

```
if (id != null) {
    fragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment);
    ft.commit();
} else {
    fragment = new MainFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.main, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

`Second way:` in your DetailsFragment's onResume() method write this code.

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            getView().requestFocus();
            getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        fragment = new MainFragment();
                        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: But I won't enter to the `else` block when I'm from notification

Answer (score 1):

This is very common situation in Android, and simply saying you can just add it to backstack. So when user presses back button he will see the previous fragment(MainFragment).

```
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(yourFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .replace(R.example.container, yourFragment)
                .commit();
```

Have a read official Android documentation about the [back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

UPDATE:

If you open DetailsFragment directly(without opening MainFragment) then you should check the back stack, if it is empty then open MainFragment manually. Here is the full code:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) // empty back stack{
          getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.example.container, MainFragment)
                        .commit();
    }
```

Comment: Since I won't add `MainFragment` if I go directly to `DetailsFragment`, I don't understand

Comment: @woprandi if you open a fragment in you activity when it starts(eg onCreate) and then you open another fragment DetailsFragment and then if you will press back button you will be directed to the MainFragment. Makes sense?

Comment: My problem appears only when I open directly the DetailsFragment (without open MainFragment before). How to always go back to MainFragment even if it has not been opened yet ?

Answer (score 1):

**Add the main fragment in the onCreate() of the activity and override the onBackPressed() in the main activity**

```
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container_recharege, fragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();

 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();

            }


        }
```

Comment: It works just by always adding MainFragment before but I don't like because I'll load all items for nothing

Comment: yes!You can replace the Frame container by second fragment directly oncreate() of the activity.If you are passing some argument to the activity.

Comment: Add the validation if user click on the notification then add the fragment in the backstack  else not add in the backstack. same flag you can apply onBackPresed().Flag is on notification click the on backPress() replace frameContainer by the main Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this on your back press or back button clicked

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragment = new MainFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: This is not the good solution, because you will call commit everytime user presses back button. Plus in this case the developer needs to override onBackPressed and handle the default function manually.

Answer (score 0):

add fragment like this

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

 FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(containerId, fragment);
 ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
 ft.commit();
```

and in your activity backpress put this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: No need of popBackStack() here, as android will handle it by itself.